# Cannot install FileZilla downloaded from SourceForge because I'm not connected to the internet?

Tags: windows-8, filezilla, sourceforge

I want to install FileZilla 3.7.1.1 on my new Windows 8 OS. I downloaded the installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/latest/download?source=dlp), and when I opened it, I got the following message:

[image: screencap describing problem]

> You must be connected to the internet to complete your installation.
> Please connect and try again.

I am clearly connected to the Internet, because I can write this question... I'm not sure what is going on, but the FTP client is a necessity for me. If there's an alternative way to install FileZilla, I would like to know it. Thanks.

Comment: What other packages are offered you must be missing something.  Just use the zip file http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.7.1.1/FileZilla_3.7.1.1_win32.zip/download

Comment: @Ramhound This is perfect, can you post it as an answer and possibly include how can I find the future zip files as well?

Comment: Apparently this is some new advertising program that Sourceforge is offering to projects, and you may or may not be able to find a zip file option: http://www.ghacks.net/2013/07/17/sourceforges-new-installer-bundles-program-downloads-with-adware/

Comment: @DJDavid98 - All I would be doing is duplicating what the artile already says.  I don't answer questions where I feel the author should have done more research before asking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem here. Try download from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php , go to "Show aditional download options" and download the best match for your computer. That will be a direct setup executable, and not some "install wizard or whatever" from sourceforge.

Answer (score 4):

On final download page just add `?nowrap` at the end of url to get the original file instead of installer.

e.g.

**[Original page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla%20Server/0.9.48/FileZilla_Server-0_9_48.exe/download)**

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla%20Server/0.9.48/FileZilla_Server-0_9_48.exe/download
```

[image: Sourceforge installer]

**[With nowrap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla%20Server/0.9.48/FileZilla_Server-0_9_48.exe/download?nowrap)**

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla%20Server/0.9.48/FileZilla_Server-0_9_48.exe/download?nowrap
```

[image]

Comment: This will save you from the worst at first (adware installer), but be careful with the FZ auto-update function. FZ is not a program to trust any more.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 is not listed as a supported client.

"Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7 are supported, each both 32 and 64 bit.'

Comment: I had to find that out the hard way, I was too dumb to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to install Offline a Filezilla SERVER the best way is to avoid SourceForge and download directly from here http://download.filezilla-project.org/

Comment: This also references Sourceforge, with a big "recommended" button for the adware-contaminated download manager. There are "clean" links in small print, but I recommend not to trust this program anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your network is using proxy authentication. You need a standalone version. You can download it from here:
http://www.oldapps.com/filezilla.php?old_filezilla=7106

Answer (score 0):

At this link you can see the download button as a SourceForge image.
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Click **Show Additional download options** then click the recommended download exe.

Your downloaded file must be the FileZilla icon